# Entity Framework Code First - SQL Injection prevention

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using EF's Code First approach with MySQL.

I'm wondering if EF in that approach has built in protection against the SQL Injection, or do I have to create SQL string query in the MySqlCommand and add some parameters to be safe from that attacks ?

I think I don't have to but I'd like to be sure about that.

Edit (code snippets example):

```
MyContext cont = new MyContext();
cont.Comment.AddObject(new Comment { Content = "my string" });
cont.SaveChanges();
```

or

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Comment(Content)VALUES(@myVal)";

MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(query);
comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myVal", "my string");
...and later execute that query
```

The 1st approach is much faster to code for me

Comment: It would probably help if you give a code sample that you think may be vulnerable to SQL injection. If you mean what I think you mean, the answer is no, you don't have to do anything special, but I can think of other things that you might mean.

Answer (score 8):

Your first code is SQL Injection proof.

Anything that you pass to EntityFramework are passed as Command in the inner IDbCommand.

But beware, if you are executing direct query with EntityFramework.

[A sentence from MSDN.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/publicsector/archive/2008/08/21/preventing-sql-injection-with-the-entity-framework-and-data-services.aspx)

> Although query composition is possible in LINQ to Entities, it is
>   performed through the object model API. Unlike Entity SQL queries,
>   LINQ to Entities queries are not composed by using string manipulation
>   or concatenation, and they are not susceptible to traditional SQL
>   injection attacks. "

Answer (score 1):

EF's LINQ to Entities (as used in your first example) takes care of preventing SQL injection attacks.